# How to search for files with 2 phrases with Regex?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ as my editor, it has Regex search function, but I couldn't do the following : If I'm searching in a project with lots of directories for a file containing 2 phrases [ "special property" and "spin waves"], how should I write the regex ?

Here is a sample file containing these 2 phrases :

The basic idea of spintronics is to use a **special property** of electrons—spin—for various electronic applications such as data and information technology. The spin is the intrinsic angular momentum of electrons that produces a magnetic moment. Coupling these magnetic moments creates the magnetism that could ultimately be used in information processing. When these coupled magnetic moments are locally excited by a magnetic field pulse, this dynamic can spread like waves throughout the material. These are referred to as **spin waves** or magnons.

I tried : special property.*spin waves

But it didn't work.

I have an idea but I don't know how to put it in Regex, is there a way to achieve the following :

[1] I've noticed if I do a search of "special property" or "spin waves", the results are instant, but I got too many files.

[2] Even if I do a search for "special property|spin waves", it's also instant, results will have either "special property" or "spin waves".

[3] So my idea is : if the the result files are in a set X for searching "special property", and the result files are in a set Y for searching "spin waves", can I come up with a Regex that return the files that are in both X and Y ?

Comment: The expression you provided seems to match the text you provided. The glaring issue I see here though is the first is that RegEx isn't very dynamic when it comes to the order of things. This means that the phrases will need to appear in the file in the same order they appear in your expression. It's also possible that the expressions being used don't have the "single line" flag, which if that's the case, `.*` won't match line breaks and therefore won't return a match if the phrases are on different lines.

Comment: The reason that [1] and [2] are so fast is that IDEA indexes all your files (you've probably noticed the "Indexing" progress bar after upgrades). This makes looking for specific words fast, but can't help much with complex regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to first search for all files containing "special property" and then searching in the scope `Files in previous search result` for "spin waves".

Comment: I completely forgot about this option when writing my expensive answer. I may even have used this technique in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the regular expression

```
(?s)(?=.*special property)spin waves
```

`$(?s)` sets the `dotall` flag, which allows `.*` to match across newlines. Then it uses a lookahead to find one of the phrases while searching for the other one normally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it in my IDEA, it didn't work, maybe it works in other systems, but in my IDE it kept "searching" and never returned any results, it's been more than an hour, it's still "searching".

Comment: I just tested it in PhpStorm. It's very slow but it worked.

Comment: `.*` isn't needed outside the lookahead, removing it makes it a little more efficient.

Comment: Do you have to do it in IDEA? You can do it in the Unix shell with `grep -l -r string1 directory | xargs grep -l string2`

Comment: Since IDEA is the tool I use to do development, I want to find a way to search files in it, and I can click on the results to see details. I've just edited my original question with an idea, is it possible ?